# GridMVC Grid Throws Cast exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, grid

I'm trying to create a simple Grid using GridMVC

Here is my **Controller code**.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var approvals = new List<Host_Apps>();
    approvals = db.Host_Apps.ToList();
    return View(approvals);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}  

@model List<TrackMiPD.Models.Host_Apps>
@using GridMvc.Html
<h2>Index</h2>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.Grid(Model,"Index").Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(data => data.ApprovalId).Titled("First Name").SetWidth(110);
            columns.Add(data => data.Name).Titled("Last Name").SetWidth(110);
            columns.Add(data => data.State).Titled("Age").Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(data => data.City).Titled("Birth Date").Sortable(true);
        }).WithPaging(20)
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried passing IEnumerable instead of List. I vaguely remember long agao I was working with GridMVC that after setting `layout= Null` it started working So ive put Layout as Null

Here is the error I get

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'GridMvc.Html.HtmlGrid`1[TrackMiPD.Models.Host_Apps]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TrackMiPD.Models.Host_Apps]'.

Comment: Are you sure the controller & view in question are tied by convention? I mean is the right view loaded from the controller? Did you try providing view name explicitly : `/Home/Index` something like that?

Comment: @SivaGopal Yes view is a loaded proprly

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a wrapper class for List of Host_Apps, That would have a list of Host_Apps. Then pass it as model to your view.

During access in view access it as:
**@Html.Grid(Model.Host_Apps)**

The same problem I had but was able to walk away with this.